# Equation of tangent with homogeneous coordinates

Tags: projective-geometry, tangent-line

Suppose $V$ is a continuous function $R_3 \rightarrow R $ of three coordinates $x,y,z$ e.g. $V(x,y,z)=x^2+y^3+z^4$.

Is it true that when
$$ V(x,y,z) =0  \hspace{1cm}(1)$$
also
$$ xV_x + yV_y + zV_z =0 ?    \hspace{1cm}(2)$$

($V_x=\partial V/\partial x$ etc.)

The reason I ask is because when $(x,y,z)$ are homogeneous point-coordinates in a plane, then $(V_x,V_y,V_z)$ are the homogeneous line-coordinates of the tangent to the curve (1). This follows from $dV=0$ because
$ dV = V_x dx + V_y dy + V_z dz$.

Equation (2) states that the tangent is incident with the point on the curve (1) which must be true of course to be a tangent.

When the assumption that (2) follows from (1) is wrong, then the ides that $(V_x,V_y,V_z)$ is the tangent is also wrong?
So I am confused about how to understand these ideas.

I have one idea. The function V has to fulfill a certain condition to be a function $V=0$ for homogeneous coordinates of a curve in a plane. Because in view of
$$ (px, px, pz)  \equiv (x,y,z),$$
it must fulfill the condition that:
$$ V(px, px, pz) = 0 \leftrightarrow V(x,y,z)=0 .\hspace{1cm} (3) $$
Otherwise the same point has multiple values and V is not well behaved for homogeneous coordinates.
So maybe this is a geometrical proof for a special situation of
Euler's homogeneous function theorem.

Therefore the V that I mentioned is not a curve in R_2.

By looking at Wikipedia, I now see that the function $f(p) =V(px, px, pz)$ in one particular point must fulfill $f'(p)=0$ to be valid which is just equation (2) ....

Comment: You need to precise what you mean by $V(x,y,z)=0$. Do you mean for all $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3$ you have $V(x,y,z)=0$?

Comment: In your equation for V(x,y,z)  should x^4 be z^4 ?

Comment: yes, sorry, it is just an example

Comment: Then it's a surface $x^2w^2+y^3w+z^4=0,$ the original $V=0$ could be homogenized to be a curve: $z^2x^2+y^3z+x^4=0$ with tangent cone $x^2=0$ at $(x,y,z)=(0:0:1)$ a cusp for it.

Comment: See my edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Theorem ([Eulers hommogeneous functions theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Positive_homogeneity)):

$V \in \mathbb{R}[X,Y,Z]$ is a [homogeneous polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomial) of degree $d$ if and only if
$$
x V_x + y V_y + z V_z = d\cdot V.
$$

Your example polynomial is not homogeneous, so it does not satisfy formula (2) by the theorem. We can also check explicitly that for the values $x=1,y=-1,z=0$, we get $V(x,y,z)=1-1=0$, but
$$
xV_x+yV_y+zV_z = 2x^2+3y^3+4z^4 =2+3 \cdot (-1) = -1 \neq 0.
$$

Comment: See my edited question.